# Apply mask to video in OpenGL

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am a freshman with OpenGL. I try to find the solution to my problem. I have recorded a video with alpha mask. The top part of video RGB and bottom is alpha. As I understand need to change my shaders, but I don`t understand how to do this.

Vertex shader

```
    private static final String vertexShaderCode =
        "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
                "attribute vec4 vTexCoordinate;" +
                "uniform mat4 textureTransform;" +
                "varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate;" +
                "void main() {" +
                "   v_TexCoordinate = (textureTransform * vTexCoordinate).xy;" +
                "   gl_Position = vPosition;" +
                "}";
```

Fragment shader

```
    private static final String fragmentShaderCode =
        "#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require\n" +
                "precision mediump float;" +
                "uniform samplerExternalOES texture;" +
                "varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate;" +
                "void main () {" +
                "    vec4 color = texture2D(texture, v_TexCoordinate);" +
                "    gl_FragColor = color;" +
                "}";
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To skip fragments you can use the [`discard`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fragment_Shader#Special_operations) keyword in the fragment shader.

You have to do 2 look ups to the texture. The first one in the upper half, to get the RGB color channels and the 2nd one in the lower half to get the mask from the red color channel:

```
vec2 c_uv  = vec2(texture.x, texture.y*0.5); 
vec4 color = texture2D(c_uv, v_TexCoordinate);

vec2  m_uv = vec2(texture.x, 0.5 + texture.y*0.5); 
float mask = texture2D(m_uv, v_TexCoordinate).r;
```

The fragment shader may look like this:

```
#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require
precision mediump float;

uniform samplerExternalOES texture;
varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate;

void main () {

    vec2  m_uv = vec2(v_TexCoordinate.x, 0.5 + v_TexCoordinate.y*0.5); 
    float mask = texture2D(texture, m_uv).r;
    if ( mask < 0.5 )
        discard;

    vec2 c_uv  = vec2(v_TexCoordinate.x, v_TexCoordinate.y*0.5); 
    vec4 color = texture2D(texture, c_uv);  
    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

Comment: Thx mate! I will try it

Comment: Now i have got some errors

Error while linking program:
ERROR: 0:2: 'x' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
    ERROR: 0:2: 'y' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side
ERROR: 0:2: '*' :  wrong operand types  no operation '*' exists that takes a left-hand operand of type

Comment: @YarikDenisyk Sorry, I mixed something, see the changes to the answer

Comment: I think it work, but little bit strange)
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CuP01VBVl9Ey0H4wH9bDftnGYpVlew2N

Comment: mistake was in the m_uv need to change
"vec2  m_uv = vec2(v_TexCoordinate.x, 0.5 + v_TexCoordinate.y*0.5);"